# Error : Call to undefined method addStoreFilter()

Tags: magento-1.9, error, stores, methods, undefined-variable

my manufactorer manage grid can't filter at store column.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magebuzz_Manufacturer_Model_Mysql4_Manufacturer_Collection::addStoreFilter()

prepare column:

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
  $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
    'header'     => Mage::helper('manufacturer')->__('Store View'),
    'index'      => 'store_id',
    'type'       => 'store',
    'store_all'  => TRUE,
    'store_view' => TRUE,
    'sortable'   => FALSE,
    'filter_condition_callback'
                 => array($this, '_filterStoreCondition'),
  ));
}
```

**function:**

```
  protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, $column)
  {
    if(!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
      return;
    }
    $this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);
  }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
   $collection= Mage::getModel('manufacturer/manufacturer')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for store filter

```
protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, $column){
    $array = explode(",",$column->getFilter()->getValue());
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $child){
            if (!$value = $child) {
                return;
            }
             $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array(
                        array('finset'=> array('0')),
                        array('finset'=> array($value)),
                    ));
            return $this;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return;
        }
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array(
                    array('finset'=> array('0')),
                    array('finset'=> array($value)),
                ));
        return $this;
    }
 }
```

It helpful to you.

Comment: If it helps, you can mark as accepted.

Comment: sr. error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause', but i had column 'store_id' in table manufacturer_store. i create 2 table: manufaturer and manufacturer-store with manufacturer_id is foreign key. but can't find 'store_id' column.

Comment: join collection with table manufacturer_store

Comment: but in Core. it don't need use join table.

Comment: Refer http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-adding-store-view-selection-to-your-modules-adminhtml/

Comment: Thanks it helped me out..I have tried to solve this issue for last 2 days..atlast find the soliution..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code instead of `$this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);`

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('in',$value));
```

Comment: tkss, but error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'store_id' in 'where clause', i had column 'store_id' in table manufactorer_store